Spring Boot entity validation activate/deactivate field constraints for different composite classes
Question:
I am implementing a spring boot microservice in which i have an entity C (with attributes name and address) referenced by 2 other entites A and B.
@Entity class C {@NotNull string name, @NotNull string address}  
@Entity class A {C cRef;}
@Entity class B {C cRef;}

For the entity A i want to make sure that name and address of C are always set (not null and have length) while for entity B i want to make those attributes optional. How is it best to implement this ?
For the time beeing i made the attributes optional and implemented the validation in the service class (which i am refactoring to a Validator class). I'm not sure if this is a good solution to solve it and would like to know if there's a better/simpler way to do it.
Solved:
After looking at the JPA documentation i had a solution using custom contraints:
PS: before you step over to the solution, i'm not sure if this is the best solution so i'll be very pleased to hear any suggestions for a better/simpler solution.
The solution:

I made the fields in Class C optional
@Entity class C { String name; String address; }


I defined a constraint annotation @CheckC :
@Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE })  
@Retention(RUNTIME)  
@Constraint(validatedBy = CheckCValidator.class)  
@Documented  
@Repeatable(List.class)  
public @interface CheckC { 
    String message() default "{field of type C is not valid, "+"message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default  { };

    Class<? extends Payload> [] payload() default {};



}

implemented the validator for @CheckC constraint annotation
 public class CheckCValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CheckC, C> {

@Override
public boolean isValid(C value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {
    if ( value == null ) {
        return false;
    }

    return StringUtils.hasLength(value.getName()) && StringUtils.hasLength(value.getAddress());
}

}

annotated the field cRef in Class A with the @CheckC annotation
@Entity class A { 
    @CheckC 
    C cRef;
}

and left the field cRef in Class B not annotated
@Entity class B { 
    C cRef;
}



this way the field cRef in A gets validated, while the field cRef in B does not get validated.
Thanks
